# Delicata squash - good outside but not sure about inside

Tags: food-safety, squash

I cooked spaghetti squash recently and put the raw seeds and pulp in the fridge and it did smell a bit strong. But I ate the spaghetti squash and it was fine. Today I cooked delicata squash which was perfect outside, firm, not discoloured or moldy and the stem was fine too. Inside where the seeds are was a bit dark and smelled a bit like the pulp of the spaghetti squash I had before but a bit stronger but not rotten. The inside after removing seeds was a bit dark and slightly squishy. I was going to cut more of the inside out after cooking and then eat it. Not sure about this though. Do I need to compost/throw it away? Or can I cut around it?

Comment: Do you have pictures? It helps...

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza no, I already cooked it but wasn't sure about eating it but I scraped out the inside again and it was fine after all. Thank you, I guess I was overthinking it but so many articles say to throw it away.